# Hide PowerPoint presentation while VBA macro is running

Tags: vba, window, hide, presentation

I have this macro that copies excel tables and charts to power point. However the power point has to be visible for it to work. Unfortunately when it is visible and while the code is running and user touches the slides the program crashes.

I use this code to hide the presentation.
Set pres = Papp.presentatjons.open(path + pptfilename, with window:=msofalse).

It works, unfortunately this code (below) which is needed, needs the window or presentation slide to be open to copy charts and tables to the presentation.

Set ppslide = pres.slides(Papp.activewindow.selection.sliderange.slideindex)

Is there a code that substitute the second code so that I could hide the presentation window while running the program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://skp.mvps.org/ppt00033.htm
The code there will help you, but does not allow me to post a copy here

Comment: Interesting - thanks for sharing. I never seen anything like it. So open a new window and can do edit but can't mess up the macro if fiddle with it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this to excel file too. I use python to open excel file and to run codes however if the user opens another excel file it become visible even though I hide it and then when the user touches the excel file while the code is running, the program crash.

Comment: I use python to call excel macro so I am not sure if I should put a code in python or VBA to not have excel visible to fiddle with, I think is VBA ?